# IHostedService always create two processes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, background-service

I'm writing a HostedService and always when I run it, it create two times the process to execute (I've checked the logs and there are two with almost the same time when should be 5 secondos each) I've followed the oficial docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

this is an example  of my HostedService

```
internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is working.");
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I add the service like:

```
services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get two different threads, the Host and HostedService, might appear as the same process running two times depending on the OS and the application used to inspect the running processes.

Comment: I have two on the hostedservice and it's executing two times the same code

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding you... Are you registering two different HostedServices but only one of them is getting executed twice? Can you provide some more information on how do you know it's getting execute twice?

Comment: Any hostedservice is creating two processes at the same time, when should create only one

Comment: Maybe you are [registering the hostedservice twice](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1404)? Can you post your full Program.cs?

Comment: something in the Ioc registration was wrong when I was registering an assembly, like @mvila mentioned, I've deleted and now the hostedService it's running as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I fixed it by deleting the code below

```
services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
```

I don't know why is still working :) But solved problem.